# ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in appreciations#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure why sometimes some users get **Missing template** error when I explicitly have specified `remote: true` in request. I cannot reproduce the error.

Missing template `appreciations/create`, `logged_in/create`, `application/create` with `{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}`. Searched in: ...

My view code

```
<%= link_to 'Appreciate',  feed_appreciations_path(feed), method: 'post', :remote => true %>
```

controller code

```
class AppreciationsController
  respond_to :js
  before_filter :load_feed

  def create
    @appreciation = @feed.appreciations.new(params[:appreciation])
    @appreciation.save
  end

  ...
end
```

I have `views/appreciations/create.js.erb` defined and working.

In the request that comes in I have

- `HTTP_ACCEPT                                    : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`
- `action_dispatch.request.formats                : [text/html]`

Why is the request not coming as a js request since I have specified `remote: true`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the answer

```
  def your_method_without_refresh
    # Put your stuff here
    redirect_to "#"          # This one is the trick
  end
```

Comment: this does not fix the problem ... read my comment below ... I will not downgrade your answer because it would be childish ;-)

Answer (score -1):

because they try to call the site directly in the browser - e.g because they copied the URL from the AJAX request somehow ... at least this is the error we have when customers do that ;-) I guess you can simply ignore it

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it happens often enough so I am inclined to think that something else is going on.

Comment: Don't agree with you, you can't ignore an error, even if it's not affecting you. I'm actually getting the exactly same error in same context, i'm digging to find the problem. Will post the answer here

Comment: @Erowlin I am looking forward seeing your approach. Nevertheless, I am still convinced, that you cannot fix this. If the user is manipulating the URL I assume he want's to do something 'dirty' he is not supposed to do. And in that case we have status code 404 in HTTP (see RFC 2616)

Comment: Where is the URL Manipulation?

Comment: @Erowlin as written - I assume the user is manipulating the URL. Your solution just fixes the symptom but not the error.  
respond_to :js indicates, that this is a action supposed to be called via Ajax. So the error does not pop up when it is called as supposed but is occurring, when calling it as "html". So I think a better solution would be to try to catch this. Why not implementing a respond_to :html and showing a error page?

Comment: Oh ok Awenkhh, i understood what you mean, and I agree with you, sorry for downvote, I fix that ;).

Edit : cannot remove -1 : "An error has occurred - please retry your request.
(click on this box to dismiss)"
Will retry later ;)

Comment: @Erowlin - hey don't worry - I can life with the downgrade - actually it's my first one - ha ha :-). I am glad that I was able to explain my point of view more exactly.